# SyntaxError: Cannot convert 0.0 to a BigInt

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, bignumber

## What, is this?

```
SyntaxError: Cannot convert 0.0 to a BigInt
```

JS being JS. What else should we expect from the creators of `NaN === NaN; // -> false` ? This is one of the worst error reasons I've stumbled upon in my entire dev life.

That must have had something to do with the horrible design of Ethers.js v6 FixedNumber class, but turns out that `BigInt('0.0')` also throws this error, so let's not blame the great team who develops Ethers.js.

I just discovered this while trying to pass a FixedNumber argument to a ContractMethod.staticCall, only to realize it wouldn't accept FixedNumber types as constructor arguments. And to make things worse, you also have no way to convert from FixedNumber to BigNumberish even if the value is as simple as 0.0, because .toString() returns '0.0' and apparently that breaks Node.js ES2020 flagship feature: BigInt.

You will get this error if you try that, which probably also reaches my top 10 of most serious programming war-crimes in libraries ever:

```
TypeError: invalid BigNumberish value (argument="value", value={ "_value": "0.0", "format": "fixed128x18" }
```

Does anyone know a way to get a safe BigNumberish with decimals from a FixedNumber? (Yes, in the case it's not 0.0 I stil want to have decimals.)

Answer (score 0):

What about converting to a *string* and *split* the string on '.'

```typescript
import { FixedNumber, BigNumberish } from '/home/salticidae/dev/js/leveros-front/node_modules/ethers';

function fixedNumberToBigNumberish(fixedNum: FixedNumber, decimals: number = 18): BigNumberish {
  // Convert FixedNumber to a decimal string
  const decimalString: string = fixedNum.toString();

  // Handling the conversion to a format without decimal points, but preserving precision
  const [integerPart, decimalPart] = decimalString.split('.');
  const paddedDecimalPart = (decimalPart || '').padEnd(decimals, '0').slice(0, decimals);
  const combinedString = integerPart + paddedDecimalPart;

  // Convert to BigNumberish (as a string)
  const bigNumberish: BigNumberish = combinedString;

  return bigNumberish;
}

// Example usage
const fixedNum: FixedNumber = FixedNumber.fromString("0.0", "fixed128x18");
const bigNumberish: BigNumberish = fixedNumberToBigNumberish(fixedNum);
console.log(bigNumberish);
```